# How to store the hcitool lescan result with C language, and print it on the terminal

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, popen

I try to capture the result of the hcitool lescan command on the terminal of ubuntu linux, 18.04.

Here is my code

```
x_pipe = popen("/usr/bin/hcitool lescan", "w");
if (!x_pipe) 
{
  perror("x popen failed!");
  pclose(x_pipe);
  return -1;
}
sleep(3);
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), x_pipe) != NULL)
{
  printf("Debug: %s", buffer);
}
```

Here is my test result

```
root@device100:~# bt_service
LE Scan ...
76:AC:17:0C:B8:CF (unknown)
23:61:7A:13:08:E2 (unknown)
27:17:7F:D4:2E:13 (unknown)
20:20:CE:D8:42:22 (unknown)
5C:AD:01:C6:EB:7D (unknown)
```

I know that I send the command to bluetooth device, and it has start scaning. But, this result from the terminal is unexpect what i thought.

I thought... (expecting)

```
root@device100:~# bt_service
LE Scan ...
Debug: 76:AC:17:0C:B8:CF (unknown)
Debug: 23:61:7A:13:08:E2 (unknown)
Debug: 27:17:7F:D4:2E:13 (unknown)
Debug: 20:20:CE:D8:42:22 (unknown)
Debug: 5C:AD:01:C6:EB:7D (unknown)
```

Comment: You open your pipe for writing and then you attempt to read from it. Which probably fails and `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), x_pipe)` is NULL, so your debug print is not executed.

Comment: But, I can see the data in the terminal. Why is the buffer empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, I can see the data in the terminal.

Because (quoting [popen manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html))

> The return value from popen() is a normal standard I/O stream in
> all respects save that it must be closed with pclose() rather
> than fclose(3).  Writing to such a stream writes to the standard
> input of the command; **the command's standard output is the same
> as that of the process that called popen()**, unless this is
> altered by the command itself.  Conversely, reading from the
> stream reads the command's standard output, and the command's
> standard input is the same as that of the process that called
> popen().

You opened your pipe for writing, so stdout of your pipe goes to stdout to your process (your console).

Just open it for reading

```
FILE *x_pipe = popen("/usr/bin/hcitool lescan", "r");
```

Optionally you can also redirect the commands stderr to stdout to capture all possible output:

```
FILE *x_pipe = popen("/usr/bin/hcitool lescan 2>&1", "r");
```